# Page loading blank for the first time in IE, on reloading renders correctly

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

In my site, I am using responsive design and loading different stylesheets according to the browser size. I am experiencing a strange issue in IE8. When the page loads for the first time, it loads blank. When we hit refresh the page loads.

Here is the page, https://www.planningsimple.com. There are no script errors showing up in the developer tools. Can anyone help me to figure out what is happening.

Comment: tried your website on IE8, facing no issues.

Comment: Tried on IE9 - the site was loaded significantly slower than it was in Mozilla, but still - I didn't have to refresh IE.

Comment: @AurA: strange, I can reproduce the error on IE8 on my Windows XP SP3. BTW, I saw this in the error log on IE (LOG: Warning: you have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.)

Comment: I am using Windows 7, may be that error is specific to Windows XP... but I am not facing any issues, yes the load time is a bit slower than usual.

Comment: @AurA: I am using Windows 7 Home 32 bit and IE 8.0.7600.16835 and I am getting this everytime i open the site in a new tab.

Comment: @UmairP: I will check out that warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed the script sources for the responsive layout right on top of the page before stylesheets. I guess it had something to do with the browser not downloading this script correctly and hence not sure of which stylesheet to load.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the errors in your page. Check it.

```
Message: Syntax error
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/9/4/main.js


Message: Syntax error
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: https://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/9/4/%7Bmain,places%7D.js
```

Comment: These js are loaded from google places and I am loading it from google's site. So I dont have any control over it.